# How to disable replace, insert drawing, look up, learn, speak, speak.., pause on the UItextfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a uitextfield inside of a uipickerview and I'm trying to disable any sort of formatting, I've used the UIResponderStandardEditActions to disable all the actions that come along with that but I don't know how to disable replace, insert drawing, look up, learn, speak and pause on the textfield.

Disabling Formatting on a UITextfield

```swift
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
if action == #selector(cut(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(copy(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.delete(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleBoldface(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleItalics(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleUnderline(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.increaseSize(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.decreaseSize(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(_:)) ||
   action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(_:))
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not try to list all the possible selectors to return false. Reverse your logic. If the selector is the one for the menu item you want to enable, return true. Otherwise return false.

Comment: Thank you I just had to set everything to false! Thank you